# Contractivity of trace distance in infinite dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information, mathematical-physics

The trace distance is heavily used in physical applications and is defined being half of the trace norm $T(\rho, \sigma) := \frac{1}{2} Tr\left[\sqrt{(\rho-\sigma)^{\dagger}(\rho-\sigma)}\right]$.

It is known that for finite-dimensional matrices $\rho, \sigma$ (so, density matrices over finite-dimensional, separable Hilbert spaces) the trace distance is contractive under completely positive, trace-preserving maps $\Phi$: $T(\Phi(\rho), \Phi(\sigma)) \leq T(\rho, \sigma)$.

I was wondering if the same holds, if we do not restrict ourselves to finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. I haven't found any resource stating that this is true for infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, but given the physical statement behind, it feels like it should be true in this generalized case as well.

It is known that the fidelity $F(\rho, \sigma)$ is qualitatively a similar measure for the closeness of quantum states, as we have

$(I)~~~~ 1 - F(\rho, \sigma) \leq T(\rho, \sigma) \leq \sqrt{1-F(\rho,\sigma)^2}$.

In finite-dimensions

$(II) ~~~~ F(\Phi(\rho), \Phi(\sigma)) \geq F(\rho, \sigma)$
holds.

I did some [google research](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1107.0354) (see eq. 2.7 and 3.11) and found that both (I) and (II) hold for infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces as well. This supports my feeling that the contractivity of the trace distance should generalize to infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, even more.

Is there any statement about that available?

Or is there any nice way how to prove that?

I'd appreciate any input/hint!